# VBA Code to concatenate cells for a range of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a product that can have multiple variants and sizes. I need a macro that can take values and concatenate them to create product SKU . For example my product is 1234. The  variants are ABF, PLC, MKLN, XTR. Sizes are 30, 36 etc. I need to to create all the variants in Macro using these values from a column.
So my final products will be 1234-30-ABF, 1234-30-PLC, 1234-30-MKLN etc. and 1234-36-ABF,1234-36-PLC, etc.
I can provide these values in column . I need to read the columns and run the macro in a loop using either & or concat function. I will provide the values . I tried the macro VBA but I cannot use variable in concat function . Please help.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet2!RC&""-""&Sheet2!RC[3]&"".""&""FR"""
```

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and include a screenshot of your data.

Comment: Will all the SKUs of a model be on different cells or on the same cell?

Comment: Why does this need VBA when a simple `CONCATENATE` formula will do exactly the same?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the Base models are on Column A, the Variants on Column B, the Sizes on columns C and the SKUs when created are on different cells, then you can use the following VBA macro:

```
Sub AllSKU()

    Dim model, myvariant, mysize, sku As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row with data
    model = Range("A2").Value
    
    Range("E:E").Value = "" 'Clear Column E -- As it will be used for SKUs
    Range("E" & 1).Value = "SKU"

    For x = 2 To lRow

        If Range("A" & x).Value <> "" Then 'Get model when cell is not empty
            model = Range("A" & x)
        End If

        Range("E" & x).Value = model & "-" & Range("B" & x).Value & "-" & Range("C" & x).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

It loops through the cells and creates SKUs on Column E.

[image]